# How to count the total number of files to be synced using rsync?

Tags: python, bash, python-3.x, rsync

I am trying to read the total number of the files to be synced using 'rsync', and read the value using the following python code, I get the following output. What code should I modify to get the **desired output**

## Output

> b'10'

## Desired Output

> 10

---

## cmd

```
rsync -nvaz --delete --stats user@host:/www/ . | ./awk.sh
```

## awk.sh

```
awk '\
BEGIN {count = 0}
  /deleting/ {if ( length($1) > 0 ) ++count} \
  /Number of regular files transferred: / {count += $6} \
END \
  {
    printf "%d",count
  }'
```

## Python

```
subprocess.check_process(cmd, shell=True, stdout=False)
```

Comment: `echo "b'10'" | tr -cd '0-9\n'`?

Comment: Even after `tr -cd '0-9\n', the output was in **bytes**, so I decoded them to **utf-8**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decoded the output to **utf-8**, and then parsed using RegEx

```
o = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
g = re.search(r'count=(\d+)', o.decode("utf-8"), re.M|re.I)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `awk` script is just looking for a line that includes a string and then printing it. Since your python script needs to read stdout to get that value anyway, you may as well ditch the script and stick with python. With the `Popen` object you can read stdout line by line

```
import subprocess

# for test...
source_dir = 'test1/'
target_dir = 'test2/'

count = 0
proc = subprocess.Popen(['rsync', '-nvaz', '--delete', '--stats',
    source_dir, target_dir],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
for line in proc.stdout:
    if line.startswith(b'Number of regular files transferred:'):
        count = int(line.split(b':')[1])
proc.wait()
print(count)
```

Comment: I wanted to keep the code modular, thus separate **awk.sh** file